# How do I connect to a VPN in GNOME-Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, vpn, connection

I used to be able to choose "connect to vpn" from the network-indicator in Ubuntu but since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 I'm only using GNOME-Shell and I can't find any way to connect to a VPN from this desktop environment. Shouldn't there be a similar button in GS's network menu? How do I do this from a graphical interface?

Comment: *Since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 I'm only using gnome-shell*, did you actually install it yourself or do you mean Unity?

Comment: What type of VPN?  There are many.

Comment: Georg, I've installed GNOME-Shell my self and it's the DE I'm referring to. Zoredache, The VPN I'm trying to connect to is using PPTP but I would prefer if the solution could work for more than one type of protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was expecting an entry in the networking menu like in Unity but I needed to add the VPN connection through `System Settings->Networking` first and then it showed up in the network menu.

To add the VPN, you must click on the "+" button which may be unnoticed.

[image: <code>Network Manager Menu</code>]