# Import OpenVPN client config in GnomeShell w/ network-manager

Tags: 12.04, gnome, network-manager, openvpn

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I've imported OpenVPN configs into network manager in the past with previous versions of Ubuntu and gnome. I have a new OpenVPN config and would like to import it, but can't find the import option.

I do currently have other OpenVPN configs working properly. I'm fairly confident that the required packages are in place. When I go to Network Settings provided by clicking on the network icon in Gnome Shell and clicking "Network Settings" I click all over and can't find anything about importing a .ovpn config.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openvpn is already the newest version.
network-manager-openvpn is already the newest version.
network-manager-openvpn-gnome is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I did it manually last time, but that is a lot of guess and check trying to figure out which setting aligns with which config line. Please save me the hassle. :-)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/78781/11831

Comment: forcefsck's link above shows you how to do it manually, but does not provide the import feature I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still access the old interface by running:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Comment: Thank you! That does get me back to the import feature that I was missing.